# AWK: get second block of text from text file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I am working on a project to extract a specific block of text from a log file on a Linux server.  The issue I am having issues with solving is getting the second occurrence of the block of text.  Our system runs a correction program and changes numbers as needed, so the first block has uncorrected valies, and second block that I really want has the corrected values.

See example of the two blocks of text below. Note the "Recs" and "Count" numbers are reduced by 1 on the second block (for corrected values).   Also the first and second (desired) block are separated by random lines of command output that changes from month to month.

Using awk, I was able to extract the first block with this command matching everything between "Report output summary" and "Grand Total All Depts":

```
awk '/Report output summary/{prnt=1} prnt{print} /Grand Total All Depts/{exit}'
```

```
Report output summary:
Department                         Type      Recs  Count          Amount
---------------------------------- ------  ------ ------ ---------------
002 FACILITIES                     Check        4      2      560,819.78

005 HUMAN RESOURCES                Check       13      8       10,688.84

010 TECHNOLOGY                     Check       94     25       78,211.24

050 TRANSPORTATION                 Check       73     27      120,350.32


Grand Total All Depts              Check      906    385       80,365.69


Random lines of text1
Random lines of text2
Random lines of text2
Random lines of text2
Random lines of text2
Random lines of text2


Report output summary:
Department                         Type      Recs  Count          Amount
---------------------------------- ------  ------ ------ ---------------
002 FACILITIES                     Check        4      2      560,819.78

005 HUMAN RESOURCES                Check       13      8       10,688.84

010 TECHNOLOGY                     Check       94     25       78,211.24

050 TRANSPORTATION                 Check       72     26       90,222.15


Grand Total All Depts              Check      906    385       80,365.69
```

Can someone spare me from further misery by giving tips on how to only return the second block of text. (Don't pay attention to the incorrect grand totals since I changed the number to fake values for the examples.)
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a funny tool `tac` like that:

```
$ tac FILE | awk '/Grand Total All Depts/{prnt=1} prnt{print} /Report output summary/{exit}' | tac
Report output summary:
Department                         Type      Recs  Count          Amount
---------------------------------- ------  ------ ------ ---------------
002 FACILITIES                     Check        4      2      560,819.78

005 HUMAN RESOURCES                Check       13      8       10,688.84

010 TECHNOLOGY                     Check       94     25       78,211.24

050 TRANSPORTATION                 Check       72     26       90,222.15


Grand Total All Depts              Check      906    385       80,365.69
```

Comment: Thanks @arkadiusz-drabczyk.  Never heard of tac, but this worked for me.  Glad I know about it now.  Thanks so much!

Comment: If you like this answer please mark it as solved to let other users
know your problem is solved. Also see [What should I do when someone
answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk` to print 2nd block with given start/end lines:

```sh
awk '/Report output summary/{++n} n==2; /Grand Total All Depts/ && n==2{exit}' file

Report output summary:
Department                         Type      Recs  Count          Amount
---------------------------------- ------  ------ ------ ---------------
002 FACILITIES                     Check        4      2      560,819.78

005 HUMAN RESOURCES                Check       13      8       10,688.84

010 TECHNOLOGY                     Check       94     25       78,211.24

050 TRANSPORTATION                 Check       72     26       90,222.15


Grand Total All Depts              Check      906    385       80,365.69
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava.  There must be something odd in my production environment, for some reason the awk didn't work for me.  I ended up using "tac".

Comment: It works with POSIX awk as well. Check this working demo: https://ideone.com/4z88Gd